# Naming convention for neighbors in grid

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, methods, naming-conventions

I'm scratching my head around this and can't come up with a good naming solution maybe someone would have a nice suggestion here.

I have a grid of cells (x,y) and I'm struggling to properly name two methods that return the neighbours of a given cell.

One method is returning neighbours that are top, down, right and left to a given cell. (4 neighbours in total, in a plus sign)

The second one is returning neighbours that are top, down, right, left, top-right, top-left, down-right, down-left (8 neighbours in total, all around the cell)

Does anyone have some suggestion about how I could name those methods to appropriately reflect what they're doing?

Comment: Whats the difference between above and top neighbours? Sounds like a conflic for me.

Comment: I think he means first method Find (up , left , right, down) second function Find (Up , left, right , down, upper left diagonal , upper right diagonal, lower left diagonal, and lower right diagonal)

Comment: I would go with find_all_neighbors and find_adjacent_neighbors even though adjacent isn't entirely correct. https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/7iub1a/are_diagonally_adjacent_squares_in_a_grid/

Comment: Adjusted the question to be more specific. Yeah @mitchell is Right. That's what I meant.

Comment: Hi Mugetsu, naming suggestion questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow because they are opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think of them as North, South, East and West.

Then you could have `GetCardinalNeighbours` and `GetInterCardinalNeighbours`

See [Cardinal Directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there already exist names for exactly that:

- [Von Neumann Neighborhood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood)

  > In cellular automata, the von Neumann neighborhood (or 4-neighborhood) is classically defined on a two-dimensional square lattice and is composed of a central cell and its four adjacent cells.

  > [image]
- [Moore Neighborhood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood)

  > In cellular automata, the Moore neighborhood is defined on a two-dimensional square lattice and is composed of a central cell and the eight cells that surround it.

  > [image]

And it is also connected of course to the pixel connectivity mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993219/7111561)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the concept of pixel connectivity to describe the neighbourhood. This is described in the [Pixel connectivity Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity).

The terms 8-connected and 4-connected are common to descibe the following patterns:
[image]

So my proposal would be to name your functions `Get8ConnectedNeighbours` and `Get4ConnectedNeighbours`.